# Why PHP foreach display query post two times?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

When I try to query some content from certain table under certain column, The echo result shows two values, one with the key 0 and other with the key name of the column.

My code is like this :

$query = "select id from nepal_posts";
    $queryExe = mysql_query($query, $connection);

```
while ($fetched = mysql_fetch_array($queryExe)) {
    foreach ($fetched as $key => $value) {
        echo $key."----->".$value."  ";
    }
 }
```

and result was like this :

> 0----->9 id----->9 0----->10 id----->10

Why there is two times repetition ?

How should I code, to get proper result ?

my db table is like :

> id -> 9, 10 title -> About Us / Om Oss, Our Services / VÃ¥r Verksamhet
>   post -> bla bla, bla bla

Comment: because mysql_fetch_array by default fetches your data in both numeric and associative format

Comment: Nobody reads manuals anymore :(

Comment: @Phil Stackoverflow is the new search interface to manuals, just as Google is "teh intarwebs" (or Facebook, depending on your age).

Comment: @deceze Back in my day we had to get up 2 hours before we went to bed, walk 10 miles through the snow to the library and RTFM

Comment: @Phil Uphill, both ways!

Comment: @Phil we don't need to, we have public vehicle here plus we can buy books easily via amazon  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`

```
while ($fetched = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryExe)) {
    foreach ($fetched as $key => $value) {
        echo $key."----->".$value."  ";
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved but i want to know what actually happened

Answer (score 5):

> `mysql_fetch_array`
>
> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   `FALSE` if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on
>   how `result_type` is defined. **By using `MYSQL_BOTH` (default), you'll get
>   an array with both associative and number indices.** Using `MYSQL_ASSOC`,
>   you only get associative indices (as `mysql_fetch_assoc()` works), using
>   `MYSQL_NUM`, you only get number indices (as `mysql_fetch_row()` works).
>
> http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: yes, personally preferred is using `MYSQL_ASSOC` as a default mode used by my db class module instead of a more hard-coded call to `mysql_fetch_assoc()`